# C kind of sorting

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, partition, function-definition

Ok so a function which arranges the elements in an array in such a way that all elements
smaller than a given value are placed into positions to the left of the elements that are larger
than the given value.

*For instance if the array contents are {4,6,2,9,1,7,3,10} and x is given as 5, then
{4,3,2,1,9,7,6,10} is a possible solution, since all elements smaller than 5 are to the left
of the elements larger than 5.*

Also, using brackets [ ] is ​ forbidden ​ except for defining the array in the main function.

Also, implement a function which prints the contents of an array. Both functions must be
implemented recursively.
you are allowed to access each element of the array only for once.

ok so  this "challenge" and I dont know if it is possible with the given restrictions. I have tried to make it with a while loop and then convert it to recursive somehow but you are not allowed to change the parameters as well. Does anyone know a solution.

I have written something but its garbage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define length 8
void selection(int array[],int size, int x){

int i=0;
int temp;

        if(( array[i]>x ) && (array[i] > array[i+1])){

             temp=array[i+1];
             array[i+1]=array[i];
             array[i]=temp;

             i++;
                selection(array+1,size-1,x)
            }
        else if(( array[i] > x) && ( array[i+1] > array[i])){
                i++;
            }

    //This is not correct 
     }
```

```
void printArray(int arr[], int start, int len)
   {

    if(start >= len)
        return;

    printf("%d ", arr[start]);


    printArray(arr, start + 1, len); 
   }
```

```
int main(){

    int array[length]={6,4,2,9,1,7,3,10};
    int x=5;

     selection(array,length,x);
     printArray(array,0,length);

return 0;
}
```

I havent implemented the a recursive solution because things I tried kept giving segmentation faults because I was reaching outside the array.

Can anyone do this recursivly without for or while. I guess you need to split the array and look at it half by half

Comment: What does _"you are not allowed to change the parameters"_ mean? You can't change the function declaration? You can't change the values of the parameters?

Comment: @Useless I meant you cant change  ""void organizer(int array[],int size, int x){"" you cant add or delete parameters

Comment: You want to change the array and length parameters as you recurse. If the first element is < x then advance array to now point at the second element and reduce length by one. If the last element is > x then reduce the length by one and you're no longer considering that. If the first is > x and the last is < x then swap them and skip them both. Stop recursing when length <= 1.

Comment: I guess the requirement though is to leave any elements that == x in the middle? That's an extra set of cases to consider at each end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void partition( int a[], size_t n, int pivot )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        if ( *a < pivot )
        {
            partition( a + 1, n - 1, pivot );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( *( a + n - 1 ) < pivot )
            {
                int tmp = *a;
                *a = *( a + n - 1 );
                *( a + n - 1 ) = tmp;
                partition( a + 1, n - 2, pivot );
            }
            else
            {
                partition( a, n - 1, pivot );
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
     int a[] = { 4, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3, 10 };
     const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

     for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
     {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
     }
     putchar( '\n' );


     int pivot = 5;

     partition( a, N, pivot );

     for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
     {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
     }
     putchar( '\n' );

     return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 6 2 9 1 7 3 10 
4 3 2 1 9 7 6 10
```

Or also with a recursive definition of the function `printArray`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void partition( int a[], size_t n, int pivot )
{
    if ( !( n < 2 ) )
    {
        if ( *a < pivot )
        {
            partition( a + 1, n - 1, pivot );
        }
        else
        {
            if ( *( a + n - 1 ) < pivot )
            {
                int tmp = *a;
                *a = *( a + n - 1 );
                *( a + n - 1 ) = tmp;
                partition( a + 1, n - 2, pivot );
            }
            else
            {
                partition( a, n - 1, pivot );
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *a );
        printArray( a + 1, n - 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
     int a[] = { 4, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 3, 10 };
     const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

     printArray( a, N );     

     int pivot = 5;

     partition( a, N, pivot );

     printArray( a, N );     

     return 0;
}
```

The recursive function `printArray` also can be defined the following way

```
void printArray( const int a[], size_t n )
{
    n == 0 ? ( void )putchar( '\n' ) 
           : ( printf( "%d ", *a ), printArray( a + 1, n - 1 ) );
}
```